# How do I get TicketDate from xml document?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to get TicketDate where ChargeID is the same as CitationCharge/ChargeID. There could be several ChargeIDs with several CitationIDs. 
The **TicketDate** in the xml is the same as xsl element `<nc:Date>` in xsl code
So I will need to check where ChargeID matches CitationCharge/ChargeID so that I get the right TicketDate.

*Desired output should look like this**

```
<ext:Charge>
    <ext:Citation>
        <nc:ActivityDate>2014-03-26</nc:ActivityDate>
    </ext:Citation>
</ext:Charge>
```

**xml**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="IXML Case Notification Test" MessageID="67084253" xmlns="">
<Case Op="E" InternalID="1617090499" ID="12125626" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <Charge ID="10906090" PartyID="16765959" InternalChargeID="1616713754" InternalPartyID="1614667066" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
        <ChargeOffenseDate>04/13/2015</ChargeOffenseDate>
            <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="42933438" Stage="Case Filing" FilingSequence="1" CurrentCharge="true" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1637029057">
            <ChargeNumber>1</ChargeNumber>
        </ChargeHistory>
        <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="42933437" Stage="Citation Issued" CitationEventSequence="1" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1637029056">
            <ChargeNumber>1</ChargeNumber>
        </ChargeHistory>
        <Deleted>false</Deleted>
    </Charge>
    <Charge ID="10906091" PartyID="16765959" InternalChargeID="1616713755" InternalPartyID="1614667066" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
        <ChargeOffenseDate>04/13/2015</ChargeOffenseDate>
        <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="42933440" Stage="Case Filing" FilingSequence="1" CurrentCharge="true" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1637029059">
            <ChargeNumber>2</ChargeNumber>
        </ChargeHistory>
        <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="42933439" Stage="Citation Issued" CitationEventSequence="1" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1637029058">
            <ChargeNumber>2</ChargeNumber>
        </ChargeHistory>
    </Charge>
</Case>
<Citation ID="5385330" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <CitationNumber>12345</CitationNumber>
    <OffenseDate>04/13/2015</OffenseDate>
    <TicketDate>04/13/2015</TicketDate>
    <CitationCharge>
        <ChargeID>10906090</ChargeID>
        <ChargeHistoryID>42933437</ChargeHistoryID>
        <ChargeNumber>1</ChargeNumber>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
    </CitationCharge>
</Citation>
<Citation ID="5385331" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <CitationNumber>54321</CitationNumber>
    <OffenseDate>04/13/2015</OffenseDate>
    <TicketDate>04/13/2015</TicketDate>
    <CitationCharge>
        <ChargeID>10906091</ChargeID>
        <ChargeHistoryID>42933439</ChargeHistoryID>
        <ChargeNumber>2</ChargeNumber>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
    </CitationCharge>
</Citation>
```

**Xslt**

```
    <xsl:template name="ChargeDetails">
<ext:Citation>
    <nc:AvtivityDate> 
        <xsl:if test="Charge[@ID=current()/../CitationCharge/ChargeID]">
        <nc:Date>
            <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(/Integration/Citation/TicketDate))"/>
        </nc:Date>
    </xsl:if>
    </nc:AvtivityDate>
</ext:Citation>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your desired output is not well-formed XML - the namespaces prefixes are not bound. What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.0 for Altova 2015. You can disregard namespaces. And output can look like this `<Charge>
    <Citation>
        <TicketDate>2014-03-26</TicketDate>
    </Citation>
<Charge>`

Comment: Namespaces can never be disregarded. But still, I do not quite understand what your code should do, because your samples are incomplete. We need a [minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - i.e. a complete XSLT stylesheet and _all_ of the output.